# picking a ID from sqlite to c# console

Tags: c#, sqlite, console

im trying to make a program where you can select a ID from my sqlite database and there by alter one off the columns my problem is making c# understand that my readline should be that ID from my database

im making a string value(named row) that is my readline but how can i tell c# that is's only should writeline the ID = row

```
sql_con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Jebus\test\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\RytterDatabase;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");

        sql_con.Open();

        string row;
        row = Console.ReadLine();

    SQLiteCommand buycommand = new SQLiteCommand ("SELECT ID,Name FROM rytter");
    buycommand.Connection = sql_con;
    buycommand.Prepare();

         buycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID",Int32.Parse(row));
         SQLiteDataReader rdr = buycommand.ExecuteReader();
           if (rdr.HasRows)
           {   
             while (rdr.Read())

              {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}",rdr.GetInt32(0),rdr.GetString(1) );
              } 
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to include a parameter in your statement

```
SQLiteCommand buycommand = new SQLiteCommand ("SELECT ID,Name FROM rytter WHERE ID = @ID");
```

Then add the parameter value with the proper parameter name @ID

`buycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",Int32.Parse(row))`;